# how to export or copy java applet parameters on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, parameters, applet

I set a bunch of applet parameters on run/debug configurations on eclipse. 
I would like to share these parameters with my co-workers, but I cannot find an easy way to copy these parameters. I looked through the plugin and project files to figure out where these parameters are stored, but I couldn't find them. Does anyone happen to know where these configurations are stored?
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch configurations in Eclipse can be saved in the workspace in one of the projects and committed under source control. When the project is imported in Eclipse, the launch configuration will be found and automatically added in Eclipse.

To store the launch configuration in the workspace:

**Run > Run Configurations... > Select the launch configuration > Common tab > Shared file**

In the text field, you specify the location, where the configuration to be stored.